# ERROR: Initializer is not a constant

Tags: c

```
int isPalindrome(char *str)
{
    static int length = strlen(str);
    if (length < 1)
        return 1;
    if (str[0] == str[length - 1])
    {
        length -= 2;
        return isPalindrome(str + 1);
    }
    else return 0;
}

int main() {
    char word[25];
    printf("Please enter a word: ");
    scanf("%s", word);
    if (isPalindrome(word))
        printf("%s is Palindrome", word);
    else
        printf("%s isn't Palindrome", word);
    return 0;
}
```

after i ran this code.
it has error `ERROR: Initializer is not a constant`.
at this line. 
What should I do?

```
static int length = strlen(str);
```

The function must have 1 argument(string of input) ==> isPalindrome(char *str)

Comment: Make an internal version of `isPalindrome` which has `length` as a parameter so you don't need the static int. Try to avoid using static.

Comment: `static int length = strlen(str);` --> `int length = strlen(str);` also `length -= 2;` then copy & update EOS (End Of String)

Comment: I want 1 argument in function 
int isPalindrome(char *str)

Comment: [sample](http://ideone.com/xipYER)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY
Error: expression must have a constant value 
==> char temp[length + 1];

Comment: I use C99......  use `malloc` and `free` instead of.

Comment: @ArayaSiriadun use a compiler that is less than 16 years old  (or if you are using a newer one, stop invoking it in 26 years old compatibility mode)

Comment: `scanf("%s", word);` should be `scanf("%24s", word);`

Comment: The answers so far suggest editing the string as you go; this is lame, it would be better to just test the string without editing (and not do it recursively if you can't change the function signature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object with static storage duration can only be initialized with constant expressions. `strlen(str)` is not a constant expression.

**§ 6.7.9, Initialization**

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or
>   thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
>   literals.

Instead, you can remove the `static` qualifier and re-write the logic by simply using additional variables:

```
int isPalindrome(char *str, size_t st, size_t end)
{  
    if (st >= end) return 1;
    return (str[st] == str[end]) && isPalindrome(str, st+1, end-1);
}
```

and call:

```
if (isPalindrome(word, 0, strlen(word) - 1))
```

---

In your existing implementation, you need to change the NUL terminator and remove `static`:

```
int isPalindrome(char *str)
{
    int length = strlen(str);
    if (length < 1)
        return 1;
    if (str[0] == str[length - 1])
    {
        str[length - 1] = '\0';
        length -= 2;
        return isPalindrome(str + 1);
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Make a copy of `word` and pass it:

```
   char temp[25];
   strcpy(temp, word);
   if (isPalindrome(temp)) {
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
but i want 1 argument(string of input) in function.
int isPalindrome(char *str)

Comment: @ArayaSiriadun Can you use a loop instead of recursion?

Comment: Nope. I can't use. T^T

Comment: @ArayaSiriadun Then you can work with a copy if you want to modify (see the updated answer).

Comment: `if (length < 1)` should be `if (length <= 1)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It's not an issue in itself rather an improvement. Otherwise, it would take one more recursion to complete.

Comment: sure. And `length -= 2;` is not necessary.

Comment: what happens if the word is longer than 25?

Comment: @M.M Buffer overrun. I simply used the same buffer size that OP used. Probably it's worth noting that it's good idea to use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) to prevent such cases.

Answer (score 1):

`static` is a like a global variable. You can't assign the dynamic value to the global variable. You can only assign the constant value to the global variable.

So try this,

```
static int length;
length = strlen(str);
```

Then In your case, you don't need to make that variable as a `static`.

**Edited Code**

```
int isPalindrome(char *str)
{
    int length = strlen(str);
    while(1){
            if (length < 1)
                    return 1;
            if (str[0] == str[length - 1])
            {
               length -= 2;
                str+=1;
            }
            else return 0;
    }
}


int main() {
     char word[25];
     printf("Please enter a word: ");
     scanf("%s", word);

     if (isPalindrome(word))
         printf("%s is Palindrome", word);
     else
         printf("%s isn't Palindrome", word);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I try this is work.
but,the output is not right. What should I do?

Comment: This code is work. but
Sorry, I forgot to tell you.
I not allow to edit main function

Comment: @ArayaSiriadun Try this.

Comment: @ArayaSiriadun Have you try this code. It is working fine.

Comment: You don't need add that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
int isPalindrome(char *str)
{
    int length = strlen(str);
    if (length <= 1)
        return 1;
    if (str[0] == str[length - 1])
    {
        str[length - 1] = '\0';
        length -= 2;
        return isPalindrome(str + 1);
    }
    else return 0;
}

int main() {
    char word[25];
    printf("Please enter a word: ");
    scanf("%s", word);
    if (isPalindrome(word))
        printf("%s is Palindrome\n", word);
    else
        printf("%s isn't Palindrome\n", word);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This code is OKAY.
but it has a little bit bug.

```
Please enter a word: abcba
abc is Palindrome
```

answer is correct.
but string is not correct
(I can't edit main. I can edit only other function)